# how do I get the request charge for azure function query?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm wondering if its possible to get the request charge in an azure function using cosmosdb input binding, from the below code:

```
        [FunctionName("RecipientRead")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "recipient/{partitionKey}/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "RecipientDatabase",
                collectionName: "RecipientCollection",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString",
                Id = "{id}",
                PartitionKey = "{partitionKey}")] Recipient recipient,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            return new OkObjectResult(recipient);
        }
```

I am able to get it this way:

```
[FunctionName("RecipientRead")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "recipient/{partitionKey}/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
             [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "RecipientDatabase",
                collectionName: "RecipientCollection",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString",
                Id = "{id}",
                PartitionKey = "{partitionKey}")] Recipient rt,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==", new CosmosClientOptions() { ApplicationName = "CosmosDBDotnetQuickstart" });
            Database db = client.GetDatabase("RecipientDatabase");
            Container c = db.GetContainer("RecipientCollection");

            ItemResponse<Recipient> r = await c.ReadItemAsync<Recipient>("1", new PartitionKey("1"));

            double rc = r.RequestCharge;

            return new OkObjectResult("ok");
        }
```

Comment: Looking at the docs, one option would be to take a `CosmosClient` instead of your `Recipient` class as the input. You would have to remove the Id and PartitionKey from the attribute at least and do the query yourself in the Function code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to obtain it based on Functions API contracts.

Please do not create your own CosmosClient instance inside the Function execution (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#azure-cosmos-db-clients), instead, leverage the binding:

```
[CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "RecipientDatabase",
                collectionName: "RecipientCollection",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString")] DocumentClient client,
```

Or if you use the 4.X Extension:

```
[CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "RecipientDatabase",
                containerName: "RecipientCollection",
                Connection= "CosmosDbConnectionString")] CosmosClient client,
```

Or you can decide to leverage Azure Functions DI https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/AzureFunctions